# JQuery Cycle Prev/Next not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle

I want to use JQuery cycle to create a slideshow where audience can view previous or next slide by clicking on image button.

I use javascript downloaded from here:
http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/int2.html

Here is how my HTML looks like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
$('#slide').cycle({ 
fx:     'fade', 
speed:  'fast', 
timeout: 0, 
next:   '#next', 
prev:   '#prev' 
});
</script>
```

And part with the slide:

```
    <div id="slideshow-wrapper">
        <div id="slideshow-control">
            <a id="prev" href="#"><img src="images/prev.png" alt="Previous" /></a>
            <a id="next" href="#"><img src="images/next.png" alt="Next" /></a>
        </div>

        <div id="slide">
            <img src="images/banner/banner01.jpg" alt=" " />
            <img src="images/banner/banner02.jpg" alt=" " />
            <img src="images/banner/banner03.jpg" alt=" " />
        </div>
    </div><!--#slideshow-wrapper end-->
```

I saw other posts regarding this matter, I tried suggested there solutions; however I still can't get the slideshow to work. :-/ Because I don't know a lot about JavaScript I am more than sure I just am missing something and/or copied something wrong.

I would appreciate if someone can have a look what is going wrong here. :-)

Comment: do you get any error in your browser console. firebug or chrome? before calling the jquery.cycle.all.js, did you include the jquery file

Comment: Hello, no, I don't get any errors at all. The file is included (<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>)

Comment: I meant the core jquery file <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>. It should be present nefore the cycle plugin

Answer (score 0):

You're not closing out your script with the right number of braces/parentheses:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $('#slide').cycle({ 
                      fx:     'fade', 
                      speed:  'fast', 
                      timeout: 0, 
                      next:   '#next', 
                      prev:   '#prev' 
                    }
                   ); //end of #slide.cycle
}); //end of doc-ready
```

Comment: I corrected my code but it still doesn't seem to be working. :-(

Comment: @Vetaxili you'll have much better luck getting help if you make the effort of creating a JSFiddle for us to review.

Comment: Not a clue what JSFiddle is. All I wanted to do was to incorporate the jquery I found on the internet. When I compare my code to the one on their website is pretty much is the same, so I have no idea why it won't work for me.

Comment: @Vetaxili this is a great time to learn! Perform a web search for the keyword I gave you (or just go to http://jsfiddle.net), mock up what you're working with, save it, and post the link.  That'll give us the ability to work with it directly.

Answer (score 0):

Also, make sure there is not another occurrence of your next and prev ids.

Ctr+F in the developer tools "Elements" tab and search for "prev" or "next".